# $\mathbb{E}({T|T_1)}$ over i.i.d random variables

Tags: probability, solution-verification, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

The problem is the following:

**Let $(T_n)_{n\leq1}$ a succession of continuous integrable, i.i.d. random variables and let $T=T_1+T_2+...T_n$. Calculate**

a)$\mathbb{E}({T_1|T})$

b)$\mathbb{E}({T|T_1)}$

**Which for a) i got that $\mathbb{E}({T_1|T})$=$T\over n$**

**But b) i got the following result which is pretty simple.**

> $\mathbb{E}({T|T_1})$=$\mathbb{E}(T_1|T_1)$+ $\mathbb{E}(T_2|T_1)$
>   +$\mathbb{E}(T_3|T_1)$...
>
> $T_1$+$\mathbb{E}(T_2|T_1)$
>   +$\mathbb{E}(T_3|T_1)+...+\mathbb{E}({T_n|T_1})$
>
> But because of all the are iid, they're the same
>
> $\mathbb{E}({T|T_1})= n*T_1$

Being this easy lead me to think i was wrong, but in some way the result makes sense.
Any advice or confirm that this is ok

Comment: $(T_n)_{n\leq 1}$ is perhaps a typo, and I suspect you mean $(T_k)_{1\leq k\leq n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But because of all the are iid, they're the same

No; i.i.d. means *independent and identically **distributed***.

Independence entails $\forall k\in\{2..n\}:\mathsf E(T_k\mid T_1)=\mathsf E(T_k)$.

- The realised value of $T_1$ does *not* affect the expected value for any of the other terms in the sequence.

Identical distribution entails $\forall k\in\{1..n\}~.\forall j\in\{1..n\}~:\mathsf E(T_k)=\mathsf E(T_j)$

- All the terms in the sequence do have the same *expected value*.

*However* $\mathsf E(T_1\mid T_1)=T_1$ but it is not *generally* true that $T_1=\mathsf E(T_1)$.

- The realised value of a term *may not* be the expected value, and quite often *is not*.

So all that may be said is that: $$\mathsf E(T\mid T_1)=T_1+(n-1)\mathsf E(T_2)$$

Comment: Yep i undestood that $\mathsf E(T_1\mid T_1)=T_1$ does not imply the converse.

Comment: You're totally right, i made a mistake because of hurry, but still nice.  Also i made a ugly statement saying that i.i.d implies the same, the random variable all measurable functions and the distribution is the "face" that we see in $\mathbb{R}$. Thanks, i'll try to make less mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer for a) is correct but the answer for b) is wrong. By independence $E(T_i|T_1)=ET_i$ for $i >1$. So the answer is $T_1+ET_2+...+ET_n$.